# How do you make a SoundCloud App submit content to a specific SoundCloud dropbox?

Tags: ios, soundcloud

I have installed a SoundCloud group recorder on my site, which does not work on iPhones or iPads. Could I instead put a link on the page to the SoundCloud app in the iTunes App store, and then have people submit their recorded audio to a specific dropbox?

See it here:  [1]: http://www.cbc.ca/q/redesign/2012/06/19/record-button-redesigning-project/index.html